# How this const value is getting changed..?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I read that constant values cant be changed but in this code below the value of `i` is getting changed through the use of a pointer. May I know how?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int i = 10;
    int *ptr = &i;
    *ptr = 20;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is 20 with a compiler warning.

Comment: This program is cheating -- breaking the rules -- and the warning reflects that.

Comment: `const` is kind of like a sticker on the back of an appliance saying "Do not open -- no user-serviceable parts inside."  But if you get a screwdriver and open it up, you can try...

Comment: will the compiler tolerate..cheating and breaking rules..dont that throws error..?

Comment: You said the compiler *did* throw a warning -- isn't that good enough for you?

Comment: @user8763383 most (if not all) warnings in C should be considered as errors.

Comment: `const` does *not* mean, "Hey, compiler: it's super important that you put this variable in read-only memory so that, no matter what, it can't possibly be modified."  It's more like, "I promise not to try to modify this variable, but I might forget, so please try to help me keep my promise, if it's not too hard."

Comment: Since the variable `i` in this program is a local ("stack") variable, there's typically no such thing as read-only memory to put it in, anyway.

Comment: @SteveSummit .....oh got that

Comment: "I read that constant values cant be changed"  --> not quite.  `const` objects should not be attempted to be changed.  It might work, it might not, it might crash.  It is UB.  Enable a warnings and heed them.

Comment: Did you check the assembly code output with compiler optimizations on ?  My compiler ('Clang') completely ignored `*ptr = 20`.

Comment: @rustyMagnet will check that..

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined* - the language does not define the behaviour of modifying an object originally declared as `const` via a pointer that's had `const` stripped from it.

On some compilers with optimisations turned on, getting 10 as the output is reasonable.

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p6